# Why z3 return wrong result

Tags: python, z3

Im learning about z3. Here is the code:

```
from z3 import *

x = BitVec("x", 32)
solver = Solver()
solver.add(x % 7 == 3)

if solver.check() == sat:
    print(solver.model())
```

The result i got `x = 3205381361`. But `3205381361 % 7 = 0`. Why this happend, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is in overflow. When you say `BitVec("x", 32)` all that means is you have a string of 32 bits. There's no numerical value assigned to it. That is, you do not specify whether this should be treated as a signed number, or an unsigned number. (Note that this is a design choice, and one that is not the best in my opinion; but this is what z3 does.)

Signed and unsigned arithmetic are different operations on bit-vectors. (Sometimes they coincide, but not always.) Modulus is one of them where there's a difference. When you use `%`, z3 interprets that as a signed-modulus operation. So, when it prints `3205381361`, that is extremely misleading: You need to interpret it as a signed 32-bit number. A signed 32-bit number has the range `-(2^-31), 2^31-1`. So, the number `3205381361` actually means `-1089585935`. (Confusing indeed: You can do a simple conversion by wrapping over `2^32`, note that `3205381361 - 2^32 = -1089585935`).

But now you can do the arithmetic as usual:

```py
>>> (-1089585935) % 7
3
```

so it satisfies your equation.

How to "fix" this? Well, in a sense there's nothing to fix; just what you wrote didn't mean what you intended. You can use an `Int` if you want unbounded integers (by declaring `x = Int("x")`), and thus avoid the whole signed-unsigned business. (But that's not a panacea, because sometimes you really want to work with machine integers, when modeling actual computer programs for instance.)

Or you can say you only meant unsigned numbers by using `URem` instead:

```py
from z3 import *

x = BitVec("x", 32)
solver = Solver()
solver.add(URem(x,7) == 3)

if solver.check() == sat:
   print(solver.model())
```

This prints:

```py
[x = 4236335589]
```

which is probably what you were looking for int he first place.

The function `URem` is documented here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#aec21d4855bd67ee88b5448d68c97a5d4

To sum up, if you're using bit-vectors, you need to be careful about your operations based on whether you want signed or unsigned semantics. See https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics-all.shtml#QF_BV for a detailed list of operations. (Another common gotcha is comparisons, which also differ with signedness. See, for instance `bvsle` vs `bvule` in the link I provided.) z3py, unfortunately, conflates all these and unless you're careful which operation you're doing, you can get surprising (but still correct!) results.

Here's the motto to remember: In SMTLib bitvectors, operations are signed/unsigned, not the values. Which is the exact opposite of what most programming languages do, hence the constant confusion about it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this solution is ok. Those are not regular integers, but integers that fit 32 bits (from 0 to 2^32 - 1) and operations made on them are all mod 2**32.

For this equation we look for integer `x` such that:

```
x % 7 == 3
```

which is equivalent to looking for integers `x` and `k` such that:

```
x = 7*k + 3
```

For `x=3205381361` (your solution) we got `k=4139312162`:

```
(4139312162*7 + 3)%(2**32) == 3205381361
```

and hence

```
3205381361 % 7 == 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explain, now i just need to change from BitVec to Int.

Comment: This is a good explanation, but it's a bit wrong in the details. The modulus operation is signed, that causes the actual problem.

Comment: @alias can you please tell me more about the problem ?

Comment: Sure, I added an answer. Here's the motto to remember: In SMTLib bitvectors, operations are signed/unsigned, not the values. Which is the exact opposite of what most programming languages do, hence the constant confusion about it.

Comment: Note that there exist `k` such that `x == (k*7 + c) % (2**32)` for all `c` between 0 and 7, so by your logic `BitVecVal(3205381361, 32) % 7 == c` should be satisfiable for every `c` between 0 and 8. However, it is unsatisfiable for all `c` except `c=3`, including `c=0`. In other words Z3 considers `3` to be the one correct result of `3205381361 % 7`. As commented by alias, that's because 3 is the result of that operation when using 32-bit signed integers and if you use unsigned modulo instead, it will consider 0 the one correct result as expected.